# JS Function Trouble - Reutning NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a salary calculator that takes the input of hours, multiplies it by the hourly rate and then gets multiplied by 52 for an annual salary. My issue comes when I try to run my function to get the salary. Whenever I press it, I am met with an NaN. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
   <form name="salInput">
       Hourly Rate <input type ="text" id="HourlyRate" /><br />
       Hours per Week <input type ="text" id="HoursPerWeek" /><br />    
    </form>


    <script>
      var a = parseFloat(salInput.HourlyRate.value);
      var b = parseFloat(salInput.HoursPerWeek.value);
      var c = a*b*52; 
     function salCalc(){ 

     document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = c;
}
     </script>


<button onclick="salCalc()">Calculate</button>
<p id="change"></p>
```

Comment: Bear in mind, that inputs may have non-number text in them, parseFloat may then return a `NaN` ([reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set value of `a`, `b` and `c` every time the function executes. You are just setting it once. Also in place of dot notation for accessing form elements, get their value by ID.

```js
function salCalc() {
     var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("HourlyRate").value);
     var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("HoursPerWeek").value);
     var c = a * b * 52;
     document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
<form name="salInput">
  Hourly Rate
  <input type="text" id="HourlyRate" />
  <br />Hours per Week
  <input type="text" id="HoursPerWeek" />
  <br />
</form>
<button onclick="salCalc()">Calculate</button>
<p id="change"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", salCalc, false);

function salCalc() {
  var a = document.querySelector("#HourlyRate").value;
  var b = document.querySelector("#HoursPerWeek").value;
  var c = a * b * 52;
  document.querySelector("#change").innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
<form name="salInput">
  Hourly Rate
  <input type="text" id="HourlyRate" />
  <br /> Hours per Week
  <input type="text" id="HoursPerWeek" />
  <br />
</form>
<button>Calculate</button>
<p id="change"></p>
```

Your problem was that you was getting the input values at page load and not when the user click the button.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script>
function salCalc(){
     var a = parseFloat(salInput.HourlyRate.value);
     var b = parseFloat(salInput.HoursPerWeek.value);
     var c = a * b * 52;
     console.log(a, b, c);
 document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = c;
 }</script>
```

fetch the values when you run the function. So keep the variables inside the function salCalc() .